# How to order a string into table format in Android

Tags: java, string, android-layout, tabular

I am receiving a countless long string from client like "1 15/8/2012 15:00 palak paneer 2 200  dam aaloo 2 100" and so my requirement is I want this string in a table format like:

```
1""""""""""""""""""""""           ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''         15/8/2012 15:00

palak paneer """""""""""""   2 """""""""""""""""   200

dam aaloo '''''''''''''''''''''''''''      2   '''''''''''''''''''''''''''' 100
```

and so on.

Any help would be appreciated.
What should I use in order to put a whole string into table format and I don't know the length of string, so we can not use hard coded values.

I have tried the `string.split` function  and I have got  an array of strings but as I said the length of string is not fixed so we can not do hard coding  so what should I have used?

This is my attempt:

```
recieved =modifiedSentence.split("~");
int length = 0;
length = recieved.length;
modifiedSentence = modifiedSentence.substring(length);
String string =String.format("%+s %+4s",recieved[0],recieved[1]);
```

Comment: i think, solution can be found using  String manipulation functions only. first column contains only alphabets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code might help you, it splits up the `received` string to rows.

```
    int start=0; 
    String[] rows=new String[10];
    int colCount=0;
    int rowCount=0,i;
    String str="";
    String received="1 15/8/2012 15:00 palak paneer 2 200 dam aaloo 2 100 a a a 3 4";
    String splittedStrs[]=received.split("[a-z]");
    String header=splittedStrs[0].trim(); 
    received=received.substring(header.length()+1);
    boolean prev=false;
    for ( i = 0; i < received.length(); i++) {
        char c=received.charAt(i);
        if(c==' '){ 
            if(str.matches("\\D+")){                        
                prev=true; 
                str="";
            }
            else{
                if(prev==true){ 
                    colCount++;
                    if(colCount==3){
                        rows[rowCount]=received.substring(start,i);
                        rowCount++; 
                        start=i+1;
                        colCount=0;
                    } 
                }
                colCount++;
                if(colCount==3){
                    rows[rowCount]=received.substring(start,i);
                    rowCount++;
                    start=i+1;
                    colCount=0;
                }
                prev=false;
                str="";
            }
        } 
        else{
            str=str.concat(c+"");
        }
    }
    rows[rowCount]=received.substring(start,i);

    System.out.println("Header ="+header);
    for ( i = 0; i <= rowCount; i++) {
        System.out.println(rows[i]);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for reply @Rahmathullah. is it working on when we dont know the length of string?????? i mean to say that the length of string could be decrease or could be increase....

Comment: Problem can be solved using an ArrayList<String>, in which u can add as many number of rows as u want. I mean, instread of using the String row, use an arraylist

Comment: thanks @Rahmathullah M Pulikkal  for your help its working ..i more little question is how to print                                 palak paneer          2         200

dam aaloo             2         100   i mean to say that the  nemeric letter are in a straight line..

Comment: hey in this code if i am giving extra space then pattern is changing.i want the formate like a bill pattern.